# Pull down zoom view inside the android collapsing layout

Tags: android

Collapsing layout image will only collapse and expand. Pull-down zoom view is not supported in the nested scroll view. If we zoom in on the image it does not actually zoom. What is the solution to zooming the image during pull down?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/editprofilelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >
    ​
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/materialup_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            >
            ​
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/materialup.profile_backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@color/app_color"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
                />0
            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="76dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:src="@drawable/profileicon"
                android:background="@null"
                app:border_width="0dp"
                app:border_color="#FFF"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"

                />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@null"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                android:foreground="?android:windowActionBarOverlay"
                style="@style/ToolBarWithNavigationBack">

                <TextView
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/editbutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_profile"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|end"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/morebutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_more_white"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|end"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/materialup.title_containermain2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="155dp"
                android:clipChildren="false"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:background="@null"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"

                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/materialup.title_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"


                    >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:id="@+id/layout3"
                        android:clipChildren="false"
                        android:clipToPadding="false"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                        app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
                        android:background="@null"

                        >

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="25dp"
                            android:layout_height="25dp"
                            android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editprofile"
                            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_profile"/>
                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="100dp"
                            android:layout_height="25dp"
                            android:id="@+id/editprofile"
                            android:text="Edit Profile"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_profile"
                            android:textSize="15dp"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton6"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="18dp" />
                        <CheckBox
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:button="@null"
                            android:background="@drawable/customcheckbox"
                            android:visibility="invisible"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:id="@+id/follow"
                            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/username"
                            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editprofile"
                            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editprofile" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                            android:textSize="18dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:id="@+id/username"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                            />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textSize="12dp"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/username"
                            android:id="@+id/bio"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                            />
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="15dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/image4"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/bio"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_link"
                            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/website"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textSize="12dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/app_color"
                            android:id="@+id/website"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/bio"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image4"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:text="FOLLOWERS"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textSize="12dp"
                            android:id="@+id/followers"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/image4"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/followercount"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textSize="12dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/app_color"
                            android:id="@+id/followercount"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/image4"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/app_color"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textSize="12dp"
                            android:id="@+id/followingcount"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/image4"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/followers"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:text="FOLLOWING"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textSize="12dp"
                            android:id="@+id/following"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/image4"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/followingcount"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/app_color"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/app_color"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/app_color"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
            app:tabMode="fixed"

            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/nest_scrollview"
        android:fillViewport="true"

        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        >


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    <com.cogzidel.hotfuse.NonSwipeableViewPager
        android:id="@+id/materialup_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```